# Rails Get All Uniques in Column of Arrays

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

So here is my scenario.

I have a column in my table called categories and it holds an array. Each array value is a different category. I am looking for a way to get all unique categories in the table.

When I use this code

```
Products.uniq.pluck(:categories)
```

It returns a collection of all the unique combinations of arrays so i need to take it a step further and get all the unique array values. Looking for an efficient way of doing that. Hope that all makes sense.

Comment: what is the result array contains please post it here, and what value you want to fetch from that collection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `.pluck` gives you an array of array. You need to *flatten* it and then run *uniq* operations.

```
Products.pluck(:categories).flatten.uniq
```

Comment: Thank you sir! Clean solution and makes perfect sense.